# Creating a reference or shallow copy of List<String> to be bind to listbox

Tags: c#, reference, shallow-copy

I'm searching for a way to be able to call a global method of logging data to both of the same text file and Listbox, in anywhere in the namespace (e.g. in different classes) for ease.

My implementation involves having a static class that logs to the text file and updating the List data.

The List data is a global variable that can be access anywhere in the namespace. Lastly, I was hoping that by binding

```
 listbox1.DataSource = logList;
```

would solve the problem. However, it is apparent that it performs deep copy and not shallow copy. :(

Is there a way to bind the reference of the list and NOT a clone?

Here are the involved codes:

```
namespace Test
{
    static class LOGS
    {
        public static void LOG_PRINT(string logMessage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (logMessage == "") return;
                // Output to text file.
                using (StreamWriter w = System.IO.File.AppendText(cls_globalvariables.systemlogpath))
                {
                    w.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now + "][" + logMessage + "]");
                    w.Close();
                }
                // Save to memory
                cls_globalvariables.logList.Add(logMessage);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
        }
    } //

    public static class cls_globalvariables
    {
        public static List<string> logList = new List<string>();

        public static string systemlogpath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\logs.txt";
        .....
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Model -> View Concept
            listBox1.DataSource = cls_globalvariables.logList;
            LOGS.LOG_PRINT("Hello");
        } //
    }
}
```

Comment: You are just referencing the list. There is not copy/ deep copy or shollow copy. What is the expectation which is not working? I guess you need a BindingList<T>.

Comment: After adding a string entry into the list, the listbox does not display anything. 

But if I interchanged them by executing the add() method first before binding the list to the datasource, it displayed the list.

Answer (score 1):

A List does not support databinding events, to have list with databinding events you need to use a BindingList.

```
public static class cls_globalvariables
{
    public static BindingList<string> logList = new BindingList<string>();
```

Or you can use a [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx)

Comment: Am I supposed to call this line again 
 listBox1.DataSource = cls_globalvariables.logList;

in the ListChanged event? Seems not working.

Comment: If you are using a BindingList the binding will do this for you. No need to rebind.

Comment: Isn't the purpose of using BindingList is its capability of databinding events? Isn't it the ListChanged event the one that you refer?

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution. First, I tried.

1.) Changing the global variable to type BindingList list.

2.) listBox1.DataSource = list; in the constructor.

3.) Adding an entry to the global variable list after number 2 but it didn't work.

4.) I also tried rebinding DataSource in the ListChanged event but to no avail.

Then I tried the following and it worked.

1.) Changing the global variable to type BindingList list.

2.) Here is the code snippet:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<String> _mList;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Model -> View Concept
        _mList = new List<string>();
        cls_globalvariables.logList.ListChanged += new ListChangedEventHandler(logList_ListChanged);
        listBox1.DataSource = _mList;
        LOGS.LOG_PRINT("Hello");
        LOGS.LOG_PRINT("Hello");
        LOGS.LOG_PRINT("Hello");
    }

    void logList_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        listBox1.DataSource = null;
        if (cls_globalvariables.logList.Count != 0)
            _mList.Add(cls_globalvariables.logList[cls_globalvariables.logList.Count - 1]);
        listBox1.DataSource = _mList;
    } //
    ....
 }
```

I added a member variable List since rebinding the List to listBox works while rebinding BindingList to listBox does not work. I still do not know why it doesn't work.